# VBA: How do you require a certain file name without reference to the file path?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to require the user to choose a certain file name but the file may be in different folders or drives depending on who is using it so the path doesn't matter. I tried using an asterisk for the path but it's not working. Any suggestions? The file will always be named "2016 latest.txt", "2017 latest.txt", etc. I want the next file uploaded to always go in sequential order which is why I have "LastYear + 1" in the code. As for the path, it shouldn't matter where the file is coming from, only the name.

```
Dim LastYear As String
LastYear = Worksheets("Main Menu").Cells(1, "B").Value

Dim fName As String
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub
If fName <> "*" & LastYear + 1 & " latest.txt" Then
    MsgBox "Wrong File. Please choose " & LastYear + 1 & " file."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: What do you mean that path is not important. You need to refer to the path somehow. If it's not hard-coded then you need to find the file somehow and get its path.

Comment: What I mean is... I don't care where the user gets the file from. It doesn't matter if the file is in any folder on their computer or on the network. The only thing that matters is what the file is named.

Comment: Because the user is choosing the file themselves.

Comment: They chose the file (only filename) or file and path together. Read @DavidG answer below.

Comment: They choose the file and path together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always let the user choose the file:

```
Sub GetFile()
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    Debug.Print fNameAndPath
    Debug.Print Dir(fNameAndPath)
    If Dir(fNameAndPath) = "yourFileName" Then
    'correct file
    else
    'wrong file
    endif
End Sub
```

Or you can search through the file system for that specific file, but this could be a lot harder (permissions, huge file systems etc.). As @Masoud stated, the path needs to be povided if it is not in the current folder.

**Edit:**
If you want the user to only choose text files, then replace

```
FileFilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*"
```

with

```
FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt"
```

Comment: Yeah I am letting the user choose the file. But I want the macro to provide an error if they chose the wrong file. However, the only credential for "wrong file" is the name, not the path.

Comment: What exactly does Debug.Print do? I'm new to VBA if you couldn't tell.

Comment: debug.print just prints out a value to the "immediate window". Press Ctrl + G to view it if not seen. I added the "Dir(path)" function, it returns just the name of the file without the whole path.

Comment: @DavidG are you sure about `Dir`? (It does not do what you say.) See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx). What if that file doesn't exist. Then it will return `""`. You can use it here but for the sake of documentation be precise of about what the function does. Good job +1.

Comment: @Masoud You are absolutely correct, the file needs to exist in the first place for this to work, thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796.aspx) operator can be used for pattern matching:

```
Dim fName, y
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
y = ['Main Menu'!B1 + 1]
If Not fName Like "*\" & y & " latest.txt" Then
     If fName <> False Then MsgBox "Wrong File. Please choose " & y & " file."
     Exit Sub
End If
```